# Confusion with Python's all(). Any solution that is easier to understand?

Tags: python, boolean-expression

I've been finding a lot of semantic bugs in due because of confusion of swapping variables in the wrong spots for python's `all()`

The boolean expression I will share is intended to make sure that all elements in X exist in the new_list.

For example, if `new_list = 1,2,3` and `X = 1..to...9`. The expression that I used returned **TRUE** when the answer is really **FALSE**.

```
>>> X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> new_list = [1,2,3]
>>> all(elem in X for elem in new_list)
True
 # Notice that a False positive returned. Not all elements in X exist in new_list
```

### Question

Since the boolean expression has caused semantic bugs in the past, is there any *easier-to-read* method? And perhaps an explanation for someone who is limited in coding?

Comment: That isn't a boolean expression, it is a generator expression, and that has nothing to do with `all`, which simply accepts *any iterable*.

Answer (score 3):

An easier (and more efficient) way around may be to use set methods:

```
>>> set(X).issubset(new_list)
False
```

Comment: This is simple and easier to understand. And the expression isn't written like Japanese.

Answer (score 2):

You read the syntax wrongly:

> ```
> X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
> new_list = [1,2,3]
> all(elem in X for elem in new_list)
> ```

This checks if all `elem` in `new_list` occure in `X`. What you probably wanted was

```
print( all( elem in new_list     for elem in X) )

            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^   
           condition to check    what to check
           to get a True/False
```

meaning: check if all `elem` in `X` occure in `new_list`.

---

The documention of [all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) explaines it with a normal loop:

> **all(** iterable **)**
>
> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty). Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def all(iterable):
>     for element in iterable:
>         if not element:
>             return False
>     return True
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if the elements in `X` are all in `new_list`, then you have to iterate for each element in `X`, then check if each of those elements is in `new_list`. You did the other way around:

```
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
new_list = [1,2,3]
all((number_in_x in new_list) for number_in_x in X)
```

That being said, using `set`s as @wim has provided is the better way of solving your problem.